# Groovy groupBy variable character sequence

Tags: groovy

I have a map of elements:

```
elemA1: value
elemB1: value
elemC1: value

...

elemA99: value
elemB99: value
elemC99: value

...

elemA7823: value
elemB7823: value
elemD7823: value
```

I want to use `groupBy` to group each set of elements by number.

The number will always be at the end of the key, but my problem is that the number can be any number of characters.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have the groupBy closure extract the part of the key you want to group by. Here I'm using the regular expression `/\d+$/` to get digits at the end of the key.

```
def map = [
  elemA1: "1",
  elemB1: "B1",
  elemA99: "A99",
  elemB99: "B99"
]

map.groupBy { ( it.key =~ /\d+$/ )[0] } // [1:[elemA1:1, elemB1:B1], 99:[elemA99:A99, elemB99:B99]]
```